# How to reorder pytest's captured output to make failure causes more visible

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using pytest to drive a large integration test that writes a lot of data to `stdout` and `stderr`. pytest displays the captured output after the detailed failure report, which means I have to do a bit of scrolling/searching to see what failed.

I know there are command-line options to disabled showing the captured output. But I still want to see it, I just want to move it so it happens earlier in the test output, so that I can see the failure report more easily.

For example, if I have this `test.py` file:

```py
import sys                                                                      
                                                                                
def test_output():                                                              
    sys.stderr.write("stderr\n")                                                
    sys.stdout.write("stdout\n")                                                
    assert 2 == 1
```

Running `pytest test.py` gives this output:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.5.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/jon/Applications/tor-browser_en-US, inifile:
collected 1 item                                                               

test.py F                                                                [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
_________________________________ test_output __________________________________

    def test_output():
        sys.stderr.write("stderr\n")
        sys.stdout.write("stdout\n")
>       assert 2 == 1
E       assert 2 == 1

test.py:6: AssertionError
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
stdout
----------------------------- Captured stderr call -----------------------------
stderr
=========================== 1 failed in 0.04 seconds ===========================
```

and I would like to see this instead

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.5.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/jon/Applications/tor-browser_en-US, inifile:
collected 1 item                                                               

test.py F                                                                [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
stdout
----------------------------- Captured stderr call -----------------------------
stderr
_________________________________ test_output __________________________________

    def test_output():
        sys.stderr.write("stderr\n")
        sys.stdout.write("stderr\n")
>       assert 2 == 1
E       assert 2 == 1

test.py:6: AssertionError

=========================== 1 failed in 0.04 seconds ===========================
```

Does pytest have any options that would let me do this?

Answer (score 1):

To modify collection order, I think you would need to write your own plugin:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/writing_plugins.html

> pytest implements all aspects of configuration, collection, running and reporting by calling well specified hooks

See [pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection) for reference.

Though in your case, I feel you might want to improve test readability simply by using an IDE instead of the shell. I personally use Pycharm, which provides a neat [Pytest integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pytest.html) to scope test results (reports + outputs), but I'm sure other IDEs might do just as well.